# Como convertir un string a tipo int o double en un objeto tipo json con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Entente convertir un objeto a int
...

```
state = {
        id: parseInt(""),
        nombre: "",
        proveedor: "",
        cantidad: parseInt(""),
        marca:  "",
        sevendepor: "",
        costo: parseFloat(""),
        iva:  parseFloat(""),
        ganancias: parseFloat(""),
        venta: parseFloat(""),
        descripcion: ""
    }
```

...
y me sale error 406 pero por que  no lo convierte en int o double en React

Comment: Puedes mostranos una captura del error en la consola?

Comment: Muestra el mensaje de error tal cual como aparece, _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Hola mi estimado amigo, primero el parámetro que le mandas a el método parseInt no tiene caracteres si en vías "" JavaScript lo detecta como null por eso te te vota error al convertir.

```
 parseInt(string, base)
```

donde:

`string = Una cadena que representa el valor que se desea convertir.`

`base= Un entero que representa la base de la mencionada cadena.`

Ejemplo:

```
parseInt("0",8)

parseInt("5455",16)
```

¡Saludos cordiales!